# Separate code between groups in linker command file

Tags: c, linker, embedded

In my linker command file I have two groups:

```
SECTIONS {

    GROUP: {

    } > MEM_A

    GROUP: { 
    
    } > MEM_B
```

I want that the (TEXT) first will be put in MEM_A, and just when it full, the leftovers will be put in MEM_B. The motivation is to use as little as can MEM_B.

I understand MEM_A probably won't be totally packed because each .o file need to sit in consecutive addresses.

Also I know I can explicitly put part of the .o files at MEM_A, but I want it be automatically, and I don't really care which code will sit where.

**EDIT**
My linker command file format is svr3

Comment: You did not specify, which target and whch linker you are using. The features depend on the linker, and so do the linker script language depend. Some provide a "OVERFLOW(<next section>) or similar command.

Comment: same to @kesselhaus, not all compiler support auto switch group/section. So you should review and do it manually. And actually, this is how you able to control the software.

Comment: I never learn all these various, slightly similar linker scripts... but some support typing things like "blablabla into MEM_A, MEM_B", the comma meaning it will first fill up MEM_A and when it is full, move on to MEM_B. Only when both are full will you get a linker error. As for what the syntax is for your particular linker, I don't know, but it is likely possible to do exactly what you want this way.